# Computational Complexity of Exponential Expression Divisibility?

Tags: complexity-theory

Garey and Johnson mentions the problem of 'Exponential Expression Divisibility" as "Not known to be in NP or co-NP, but solvable in pseudo-polynomial time using standard GCD Algorithms".

Pseudo-polynomial compared-to/in-terms of what value/variable? Can someone help with the explicit complexity measure of the problem?

Comment: Pseudo-polynomial compared to input size. The input size is always what we compare the running time to.

Comment: much thanks. but there are quiet a few variables in the Input. Is it w.r.t. the 'Maximum element in Set A/B' or the GivenBase^'Maximum element in Set A/B'. I think its the former. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: Its with respect to the bit-length of the entire input.

Comment: How about providing a self-contained definition of the Exponential Expression Divisibility problem, if you'd like to ask about algorithms for it?